# Switch inside TextInputLayout

Tags: android, layout, textinputlayout

I would like to accomplish the task shown in the two images below; more precisely, be able to "extend" somehow the TextInputLayout to the Switch so that it is included in the forementioned layout, along with the TextInputEditText.

All tries I have done so far have failed me.

The XML code for one item is listed below:

```
                        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/myprofile_twitter"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_grey_800"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Twitter" />

                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <Switch
                            android:id="@+id/twitter_switch"
                            android:layout_width="45dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

And here are the two images (image 1 is how it's currently presented and image 2 is what I would like to accomplish - see Linkedin). Though, not sure if it's possible to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you simply want a border around both the `EditText` and `Switch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not ideal this is a workaround to get behavior similar to what you're looking for. You can also change or create another border for the `Switch` to match an unfocused `TextInputLayout` state.

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/myprofile_twitter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Twitter" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/twitter_switch"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:padding="18.5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-19dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>

        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <padding
            android:right="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, the TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText have an animation on focus, that moves the hint as a title for the box, as far as I can tell from the code this will not keep that animation. (see Facebook box)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved that format with this sample layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="LinkedIn"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/twitter_switch"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, the TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText have an animation on focus, that moves the hint as a title for the box, as far as I can tell from the code this will not keep that animation. (see Facebook box)